# Install SQL Express 2005 over 2012

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon EC2 Windows 2012 with SQL Server Express 2012, but I need SQL server 2005, What can I  do to accomplish this?

Thank you

Comment: Have you consiidered migrating your data from 2005 to 2008, and then from 2008 to 2012?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should instead use [a version of SQL Server that is still supported](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlreleaseservices/archive/2011/01/27/end-of-mainstream-support-for-sql-server-2005-and-end-of-service-pack-support-for-sql-server-2008-sp1.aspx).  Also, [SQL Server 2005 is not supported on Windows Server 2012](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2681562).

Sorry.

If, for whatever reason, you have to have 2005, you'll need Windows server 2008 or 2008 R2.  You'll have to copy the installer onto the Amazon EC2 instance and install it over remote desktop.